# How can I write this JavaScript iteration function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JS function that returns a list of ".youtube" elements, loops through the selector, and calls another function. The JavaScript function is working beautifully, but I want to translate it into jQuery. Here's the JS function, which works correctly:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll(".youtube");
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    getVideos(videos[i]);
}
```

Now here's my attempt at translating it into jQuery:

```
$(".youtube").each(function(i, youtube){
    getVideos(youtube[i]);
});
```

This doesn't work. Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3y3yvxq/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for index in jQuery **[each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**, `youtube` refers to the element

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element. ( Taken from https://api.jquery.com/each/ )

```
$(".youtube").each(function(i, youtube){
    getVideos(youtube);
    // or getVideos(this);
});
```

Comment: Duh. I feel stupid now. I'll accept when timer runs out.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like this:

```
$(".youtube").get().forEach(getVideos);
```

...provided `getVideos` only looks at its first argument and not subsequent ones, as it will get called with three arguments: The element, its index, and the array we're looping over (which is what `.get()` gives us, a true JavaScript array).

Or the "less jQuery" way:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".youtube"), getVideos);
```

---

I should note that `forEach` is ES5+ (e.g., circa 2009), so IE8 doesn't have it, as IE8 was released before the ES5 specification was finalized. All *modern* browsers do.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, thanks for your input.